# Date extension method ambigious call?

Tags: c#, datetime

I was creating some datetime extension methods in C#, started my class:

```
public static class DateExtensions
    { 
        public static DateTime WeekStartDate(this DateTime dt)
        {
            DateTime _returnDateTime = dt.AddDays(-((dt.DayOfWeek - Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)));
            return _returnDateTime;
        }

 public static DateTime WeekEndDate(this DateTime dt)
        {
            return dt.WeekStartDate().AddDays(6);
        }
    }
```

Everything builds, however when I Run my project I get an error stating:

`The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'RIMS.Extensions.DateExtensions.WeekStartDate(System.DateTime)' and 'RIMS.Extensions.DateExtensions.WeekStartDate(System.DateTime)'`

Pointing to this:

```
Line 30:         public static DateTime WeekEndDate(this DateTime dt)
Line 31:         {
Line 32:             return dt.WeekStartDate().AddDays(6);
Line 33:         }
Line 34:
```

I must not be understanding something obvious, there is only one WeekStartDate method, what makes it ambigious?  I'm posting my whole code cause I have tried everything, cleaning, rebuilding, closing vs, etc:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace RIMS.Extensions
{
    public static class DateExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns week start date.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dt">this - the current date</param>
        /// <returns>datetime</returns>
        /// usage: 
        /// DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        /// DateTime weekStart = dt.WeekStartDate();
        public static DateTime WeekStartDate(this DateTime dt)
        {
            DateTime _returnDateTime = dt.AddDays(-((dt.DayOfWeek - Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)));
            return _returnDateTime;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns week end date.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dt">this - the current date</param>
        /// <returns>datetime</returns>
        /// usage: 
        /// DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        /// DateTime weekEnd = dt.WeekEndDate();
        public static DateTime WeekEndDate(this DateTime dt)
        {
            return dt.WeekStartDate().AddDays(6);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns month start date.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dt">this - the current date</param>
        /// <returns>datetime</returns>
        /// usage: 
        /// DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        /// DateTime monthStart = dt.MonthStartDate();
        public static DateTime MonthStartDate(this DateTime dt)
        {
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns month end date.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dt">this - the current date</param>
        /// <returns>datetime</returns>
        /// usage: 
        /// DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        /// DateTime monthEnd = dt.MonthEndDate();
        public static DateTime MonthEndDate(this DateTime dt)
        {
            return DateTime.Now.MonthStartDate().AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month) - 1);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns whether a date falls on a weekend
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">this - the current date</param>
        /// <returns>boolean</returns>
        /// usage: 
        /// DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        /// bool itsAWeekend = dt.IsWeekend();
        public static bool IsWeekend(this DateTime value)
        {
            return (value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns whether a date falls between a start and end date
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dt">this - the current date</param>
        /// <param name="startDate">Beginning date to compare</param>
        /// <param name="endDate">End date to compare</param>
        /// <param name="compareTime">Optional bool whether or not to compare the time</param>
        /// <returns>boolean</returns>
        /// usage: 
        /// DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        /// Boolean isBetween = dt.IsBetween(someStartDate, someEndDate);
        public static bool IsBetween(this DateTime dt, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, Boolean compareTime = false)
        {
            return compareTime ?
               dt >= startDate && dt <= endDate :
               dt.Date >= startDate.Date && dt.Date <= endDate.Date;
        }
    }
}
```

Here also is my list of references:

[image]

I am not seeing the reference of my project.

Comment: Resharper even flags it but doesnt recommend anything to perform, as I said the project builds fine with no errors...

Comment: Clean the solution and retry it.  If that doesn't work, close out of Visual Studio and reopen it

Comment: Cleaned and rebuilt several times, tried on another PC same issue.

Comment: What are your references in the project? What if you try to remove reference to this project?

Comment: I pasted his code into VS and it compiled and ran with no errors or warnings.

Comment: Habib so you cant call an extension method directly from the extension class?  That seems odd

Comment: You must have another copy of that method in your project somewhere. Do a text search for it if you have to.

Comment: yes you can.....  LINQ is nothing but extension methods...

Comment: @JonH, no I was wrong. just tried your code in wrong place.

Comment: @Habib - I thought i was going crazy, at least you confirmed it.

Comment: @JonH maybe try 2 different, definitely unique names and see if you still get the error?

Comment: @test - i tried that as well before i posted this, changed the entire name of a function, and still the same issue.

Comment: @JonH Sounds like you have a duplicate reference to your project. Presumably a dll reference  and a project reference to RIMS.Extensions assembly.

Comment: Try this: rename your method. Then go to where you call that method, right click, and go to its definition. That should find your dupe.

Comment: Jon B - I havent even begun to actually use the extension method.  I am merely creating them.

Comment: What if you try to compile this project only? Is that the same as compiling the whole solution?

Comment: @JonH, try `return DateExtensions.WeekStartDate(dt).AddDays(6);`, not really sure if it would change anything, but just try and see

Comment: @TomasPastircak - This .cs file is inside this one solution, in fact this is just one project.

Comment: You're calling `WeekStartDate` from `WeekEndDate`. If you rename `WeekStartDate` (but don't change the call to it), you might be able to find the rogue duplicate.

Comment: Check your references, make sure the project doesn't have a reference back to itself.

Comment: I'm interested to see how this concludes

Comment: What if you comment out WeekEndDate method? Are you able to compile?

Comment: Builds fine for me when I reference it from a class lib in a console app project in VS 2012.

Comment: @Habib now that seems to work, the question is why doesn't `dt.WeekStartDate().AddDays(6);`

Comment: @JonH, Well that means you definitely have another method `WeekStartDate` somewhere in your code. Or there is some weird reference issue, Try creating a separate console app, with just the extension class, and see if you get any error.

Comment: This is the strangest issue I've ever run into...I'll try to create a new project and see what happens.

Comment: @JonH Can you provide the simplest solution in a zip that reproduces this error so we can inspect it

Comment: If you have a file reference issue Cleaning is not the solution, you have to manually remove the reference.

Comment: Okay I am looking at all my references (I assume you mean references within my project).  But since this is simply a class file within my project what reference am I looking for.  If it helps this is a web form project.

Comment: @JonH If your Webproject is named says WebApplication3, then under Reference look one with the same name (WebApplication3) that is the problem. I reproduce the same steps as for WindowsForms and got the same results.

Comment: I have too.....Even if I create a new web form project, copy the exact code, change the "Build Type" to Content for the DateExtensions.cs file.  Build my code, run my code, exception thrown...

Comment: If you remove all the other unrelated projects, zip up the sln with the run-time exception, we can take a look

Comment: Im curious, do you resolve this issue?

Comment: No i did not but I can use what Habib posted.

Comment: Strange, i can use your extention this way wihout problem 
var x = DateTime.Today.WeekEndDate(); Did you perform a search for "WeekEndDate" at project level?

Comment: @LukeHutton here it is shared https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8qpT3SMNA4ASGFrTVZVQUl2QWs/edit?usp=sharing if I run the project it says ambigious method.  Please look at the app_code/extensions folder.

Comment: Okay I see the issue the extensions folder is within the app code folder, hence the ambiguous error message.

Comment: Yah I've seen someone run into that issue as well when they had the source within the app_code folder. I think the code in app_code get's dynamically compiled at runtime so you have two definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well...I see the reason why it wasn't working.  I had the extension code folder within the App_Code folder.  The minute I removed it from there it worked!

Sorry folks!

Comment: This is because the content in App_Code gets compiled dynamically. This is historical. Apparently Visual Web Developer needed this to have IntelliSense in the designer. When the concept of Website came to .Net 2.0 you had to put all your classes that weren't code behind into the App_Code. That's my interpretation of https://forums.asp.net/t/1401061.aspx. Shoutout to Luke Hutton who had the first idea that the dynamic compilation could be the cause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066791/date-extension-method-ambigious-call/23087058#comment35294073_23066791.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the problem. 
I created a WinForm project and added your extenssion class. Just one project.
Compile and then i added a file reference to the exe file from bin\Debug folder, run the app and got the same exception.
EDIT:
Reproduced the steps for a Web project and get the same result.
[image]
[image]

Comment: That doesn't sound like the same - he said a clean didn't change anything, in this case a clean would break the build.

Comment: A clean does not resolve this bad reference, in the next compilation he is going to get the same exception. If this is the problem he have to manually remove the file reference.

Comment: @Elio.Batista - Which file reference?  This is simply a class file within my project.  Where am I looking within my project for this?

Comment: Within your same project @JonH, look under Reference node, i'm pretty confident that you will find in your project a reference to itself.

Comment: THis is my issue there is no reference to itself.  I can post a screen shot if you'd like?

Comment: Ok, I posted my screen shot, please post yours.

Comment: I posted mine but can barely see yours, can you link to it via imgur?

Comment: What is the name of yoyr project?

Comment: `RIMS` is the name of my project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50638/discussion-between-elio-batista-and-jonh)

Answer (score -1):

For being sure that you don't have 2 methods with the same name, just rename the WeekStartDate in your extension and see if it can be compiled or not, it it compiles with no error it means that you have same method in some where else, then right click on it on choose go to definition.

Comment: Please read the comments above...I have tried renaming them with the same issue.